# How to Include a File in php

Tags: php, include

I am haviing issue in including file in php

```
`<?php
 include "../../db/db_connection.php";`
```

Error

```
Warning: include(../../db/db_connection.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/practice/Blogs/actions/accounts/general.php on line 2
```

Here is my directories

[image: Image for my directories]

I try to check it in terminal and the file is opened normally but giving error on the localhost

Comment: try `include(../db/db_connection.php)`

Comment: getting same error @SlavaRozhnev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use DIR, also you have only one level "../"

```
include __DIR__ . '/../db/db_connection.php';
```

But it`s better to use **require_once** for config files

Comment: Warning: require_once(../../db/db_connection.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/practice/Blogs/actions/accounts/general.php on line 3
@Andrey Bessonov

Comment: Change require_once(../../db/db_connection.php) to require_once(\_\_DIR__ . '/../db/db_connection.php')

Answer (score 0):

You may check you file location first, `include()` and its relatives take filesystem paths, not web paths relative to the document root.

To get the parent directory `use ../`

```
include('../db/db_connection.php');

include('../../db/db_connection.php');
```

Comment: Warning: require_once(../../db/db_connection.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/practice/Blogs/actions/accounts/general.php on line 3

Comment: you may share your directory structure screenshot.
you are missing your directory location where you put your files.